# Add plot title and axis labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have written some code that plots the corners of a square and the center with the corresponding value assigned to that square. The coordinates are stored as two numpy arrays in the following way:

```
coorCenter = np.array([[ 19.99812616,  39.9060875 ],
              [-20.00187384,  39.9060875 ], 
              [-20.00187305,  -0.10565157], 
              [ 19.99812695,  -0.10565157], 
              [-19.99999842, -40.02347813], 
              [ 20.00000158, -40.02347813]])

coorCorner = np.array([[ 4.00000000e+01, -6.00000000e+01],
              [ 4.00000000e+01,  6.00000000e+01], 
              [ 4.00000000e+01, -2.00000000e+01], 
              [ 4.00000000e+01,  2.00000000e+01], 
              [-4.00000000e+01,  6.00000000e+01],
              [ 6.93889390e-15,  6.00000000e+01], 
              [-4.00000000e+01, -6.00000000e+01],
              [-4.00000000e+01,  2.00000000e+01],
              [-4.00000000e+01, -2.00000000e+01],
              [ 6.93889390e-15, -6.00000000e+01], 
              [-5.62152798e-03,  1.97182625e+01],
              [ 4.75348769e-06, -2.00704344e+01]])

Values = [0.00308649, -0.00308693, -0.03431792,  0.03431309,  0.1164378,  -0.11643781]
```

My current code is as follows but I have troubles adding a title and axis labels

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
from Assembly import AssembleCenterCoordinates

def centerPlot(G, A, Values, axis_size):
    coorCenter = AssembleCenterCoordinates(G, A)
    coorCorner = G.get('coor')
    
    # round numbers to 2 decimal points
    Values = [np.format_float_positional(Values[i], precision=2) for i in range(len(Values))]
    
    fig = pyplot.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_ylim(-axis_size,axis_size)
    ax.set_xlim(-axis_size,axis_size)
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    
    pyplot.scatter(coorCenter[:,0],coorCenter[:,1])
    pyplot.scatter(coorCorner[:,0],coorCorner[:,1])
    
    for i,j,k in zip(coorCenter[:,0],coorCenter[:,1],Values):
        # annotating our points and offsetting the text
        ax.annotate(str(k), xy=(i,j), xytext=(5,5), textcoords='offset points')
    pyplot.show()
```

Here is how my current plot looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpPQp.png

And here is how I would like it to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A0X5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before `pyplot.show()`, add these lines:

```py
pyplot.title('Title here')
pyplot.xlabel('X-Label')
pyplot.ylabel('Y-Label')
```